# Node JS "require" returns empty objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I'm currently trying to use 'cron-parse' in my Angular project and the object is failing to recognize the functions. In a fresh project, I was able to successfully configure nodejs and successfully use the cron parser. However, in the project that my team is using, I cannot. I also tried loading 'cron' with the same results.

I understand that require will do this if circular dependencies exist. I used **Madge** to see if this is the case, and my project does not have circular dependencies.

I also compared the tsconfig.app.json and tsconfig.spec.json files between the working project and the broken one. I did not see anything extra ordinarily different.

I'm new to developing web applications and at a loss at the moment. Any other pointers to pinpoint why my modules will not load?

```
var parser = require('cron-parser')
var options = {
  currentDate: new Date('Wed, 26 Dec 2012 12:38:53 UTC'),
  endDate: new Date('Wed, 26 Dec 2012 14:40:00 UTC'),
  iterator: true
};

try {
  var interval = parser.parseExpression('*/22 * * * *', options);
  console.log("parser: " + parser)

  while (true) {
    try {
      var obj = interval.next();
      console.log('value:', obj.value.toString(), 'done:', obj.done);
    } catch (e) {
      break;
    }
  }
```

EDIT: Why I think the broken project is returning an empty object:

1. In the working project, the console output is `parser: function CronParser() {}`
2. In the broken project, the console output is `parser: [object Object]`
3. JSON.Stringify outputs {}
4. I get the error parseExpression does not exist.

Comment: What does "failing to recognize the functions" and "I cannot" mean? Are there error messages? Do you have cron-parser installed in directory of the project?

Comment: @AndyRay In the project that is working, the console outputs: parser: function CronParser() {}

In the project that is not, the console outputs: parser [object Object]
Using JSON.stringify on the object, it outputs {}

I also see an exception that "parseExpression" does not exist.

Comment: Yes, I do have the cron-parser installed in both projects. But I'll double check tomorrow .... just incase.

Comment: That different output is strange. Is it the same cron-parser version in both folders? In the bad folder you could `rm -rf node_modules` and then install cron-parser using npm. Are you using a node version manager (`nvm`) that's switching your node version between folders? Is one project using typescript and the other isn't?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code (after having simplified it a bit) and it worked:

```
import { parseExpression } from 'cron-parser';

const options = {
  currentDate: new Date('Wed, 26 Dec 2012 12:38:53 UTC'),
  endDate: new Date('Wed, 26 Dec 2012 14:40:00 UTC'),
  iterator: true
};

const iterable = {
  [Symbol.iterator]: function () {
    return parseExpression('*/22 * * * *', options);
  }
}

for(const date of iterable) {
  console.log(date);
}
```

I just got this warning

> Warning:
> C:\Users\Guerric\Downloads\angular-ivy-sehrn2\src\app\hello.component.ts
> depends on 'cron-parser'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause
> optimization bailouts. For more info see:
> https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Indeed, cron-parser is packaged as CommonJS which is a pretty old standard, initially designed for server-side code. It is much less statically analyzable than ECMAScript modules, which means less tree-shakable (the build may include unused code and increase the bundle size).

In general in Angular, prefer using libraries packaged as ECMAScript modules instead of CommonJS.